# Формирование динамической ссылки

Tags: php

Добрый день.

У меня вопрос. Я формирую ссылки в скрипте.
И хочу лолучать значения в $_GET
что не так со сылкой. Массив $_GET пустой

```
 echo '<a href= ./?page=' .$total. '>>></a>'
```

Как можно еще сформировать ссылку?

```
 public function Limit()
{
    $page2right='';
    $page2left='';
    $page1left='';
    $page1right='';
    $nextpage='';
    $pervpage='';

    $page = $this->escape($this->clean($this->getPage()));
    $pageinlist = $this->escape($this->clean($this->getPageinList()));


    $total = ceil(self::CountBase()/ $pageinlist);
    $total = (int) $total;

    if (empty($page) or ($page < 0)) {
        $page = 1;
    }
    if ($page > $total) {
        $page = $total;
    }

    // Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад
    if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href= ./?page=1><<</a> <a href= ./?page='. ($page - 1) .'><</a> ';
// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед
    if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' <a href= ./?page='. ($page + 1) .'>></a> 
                               <a href= ./?page=' .$total. '>>></a>';

// Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть
    if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href= ./?page='. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a>  ';
    if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href= ./?page='. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a>  ';
    if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = '  <a href= ./?page='. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>';
    if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = '  <a href= ./?page='. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>';

// Вывод меню
    return '<li>'.$pervpage.$page2left.$page1left.'<span>'.$page.'</span>'.$page1right.$page2right.$nextpage.'</li>';

}
```

Вот создание класса и выхов методов .

```
                $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? mb_substr(
                htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_GET['page']))), 0, 20, 'UTF-8'
            ) : 1;

            $pageinlist = PAGEINLIST;

            $paginate=new Paginator($page, $pageinlist);
            $paginate->CountBase();
            echo $paginate->Limit();
```

$_GET пустой и все тут.

Comment: `sprintf('<a href="/?page=%s">&gt; &gt;</a>', $total);` где то так

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Даже, если закрыть глаза на... всё, то нужен, хотя бы, кусок скрипта. Иначе, сложно сказать что не работает. Желательно, чтобы был и текущий результат генерации кода.

Comment: Идите и читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php Не забудьте пройти по ссылкам в разделе **Смотрите также**.

Comment: ***Notice: Undefined index: page*** 


echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $_GET['page'] );
echo "</pre>";exit;

Comment: @Visman А чот там можно прочитать про echo ?? Ты о чем?

Comment: @Vitaly Ну вот я добавил кода ....

Comment: Хм, интересно. У меня этот код сработал нормально и $_GET['page'] содержал верное значение. Используется ли какой-либо фреймфорк? Если да, то, вероятно, в нём используется механизм защиты и доступ к $_GET, $_POST и пр. переменные осуществляется через стандартные средства, а сами массивы очищаются. Кроме того, советую, использовать кавычки для аттрибута href (`<a href="./?page=N">N</a>`), а так же, указывать полый адрес, а не "./". В данном случае, это всё будет передаваться на index.php.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, о вашей первой версии вопроса. Формулируйте вопросы полно и понятно не только для вас, но и для тех кому вы их задаете.

Comment: @Vitaly Фреймверка на использую. Я вызываю массив $_GET в двух файлах.  В одном действительно отрабаатывает.
 В другом Пусто. 
Область Видимости $_GET Везде же должна быть. Все они соединены. Общим файлом. В чем может быть беда.

Comment: Да, `$_GET` один из глобальных переменных. Если в одном файле показывается значение, а во втором нет, то нужно смотреть что происходит с этим массивом. Нет ли кода очистки переменной или редиректа с потерей переданных параметров. Причин много. Для проверки, можно включить вывод ошибок (если они не включены): `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`. Возможно, есть место некритичной ошибке, после которой скрипт продолжает работу, но уже с некорректными данными. Посмотри что пишется в логи web-сервера (Apache/Nginx/IIS). Есть ли там вызовы с get параметрами.

Comment: @Vitaly
Да логи пишутся 
***acess.log***
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Oct/2017:13:24:38 +0300] "GET /sit.my/MY_DZ/ANT/?page=3 HTTP/1.1" 200
***error.log***
по времени 13:24:38 записи нету.

**error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');** Включил все норм. ошибок нет. Масив $GET пустой в одном файле. В другом все норм.

Comment: Тогда выход один: начни выводить значения всего массива $_GET (var_dump или print_r) с начала файла. В файле, скорее всего есть include / require. Выведи до них, потом после и так далее. Для уточнения: в ответе опечатка или используется переменная $GET, вместо $_GET?